# validation a unique form fields with kendo UI

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, kendo-ui

I have a form with Kendo UI. I want name input to be unique while submitting the form.
How to set this validation with Kendo UI?
Also is validation related to Kendo UI or to the controller's action ?

here is the code:

```
 @(Html.Kendo().Grid(Model)
    .Name("GridConstante")
    .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width:900px;height:380px" })
    .Editable(editing => 
        {
            editing.Mode(GridEditMode.InCell);
            editing.DisplayDeleteConfirmation("Êtes-vous sûr de vouloir supprimer cette constante ?");
        })
    .ToolBar(commands =>
    {
        commands.Save().CancelText("Annuler").SaveText("Valider").HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width:100px;float:right" });
        commands.Create().Text("Ajouter").HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width:100px;float:right" });

    })

    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
            .Ajax()
            .Read("Liste", "Constante")
            .Create("Save", "Constante")
            .Update("Save", "Constante")
            .Destroy("Delete", "Constante")
           .Model(model => model.Id(p => p.ConstanteId))
           .Events(e => e.RequestEnd("OnKendoGridAdministrationSaveEnd"))
            )

    .Columns(columns =>
    {
        columns.Bound(p => p.ConstanteId).Groupable(false).Hidden();
        columns.Bound(p => p.NOM).Width(100).Title("Constante") ;
        columns.Bound(p => p.LIBELLE).Width(250).Title("Libellé");
        columns.ForeignKey(p => p.KIND, ViewData["ConstanteType"] as SelectList).Width(35).Title("Type").HtmlAttributes(new { style = "text-align:center" }) ;
        columns.Bound(p => p.VALE).Width(80).Title("Valeur").Format("{0:N3}").HtmlAttributes(new { style = "text-align:right" }); 
        columns.Command(command => command.Destroy().Text("supprimer")).Width(80).Title("Action");
    })
    .Scrollable()
            .Selectable(selectable => selectable
                .Mode(GridSelectionMode.Single)
                .Type(GridSelectionType.Row))
    .Navigatable()
    .Events(e => e.Remove(@"function(e){
                    setTimeout(function(){
                        $('#GridConstante').data('kendoGrid').dataSource.sync()
                    }
                    )}"))
  )
```

Please tell me how can i fix this problem ?

Comment: Did you find your answer yet?

Comment: **not yet**   jwatts1980@

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kendo grid cannot tell whether the value is unique. That is something that you have to program in your controller in the `Save` action.

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
public ActionResult Save([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request, Model m)
{
    if (m != null && ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        //perform validation stuff here.
        //If the name is not valid, add an error to the ModelState.
        ModelState.AddModelError("NOM", "Your error text");

    }            

    //and return the model state along with the Json
    return Json(new[] { m }.ToDataSourceResult(request, ModelState));
}
```

Here is a custom validation example on the Kendo website: http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/web/grid/editing-custom-validation.html

Comment: ToDataSourceResult hasn't been reconized even i have the Kendo.Mvc.dll assembly downloaded @jwatts1980

Comment: It is an extension method. Add `using Kendo.Mvc.Extentions;` in the controller.

Comment: **using Kendo.Mvc.Extentions; isn't reconized also **@ jwatts1980

Comment: is there a solution using javascript ?? @jwatts1980

Comment: If you click on the Kendo.Mvc under References, then look under properties, what it's the version you have? Extensions it's apart of the Kendo.Mvc library that I am using. I have no other Kendo libraries.

Comment: Sure you could create some crazy Jquery code to capture the Save button click, then create an Ajax post back to the server to validate the name, then use JavaScript to process the custom message that you return and show an error or allow the Save to go through.... but geez, that's a dirty and time consuming solution.

Comment: thanks alot for your help  jwatts1980 ,i have that kendo.Mvc library and it's ok for using Kendo.Mvc.Extentions; but even that  [DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest isn't reconized

Comment: `DataSourceRequest` is apart of `using Kendo.Mvc.UI;`